# Bad review audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing Reopen Votes and I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772116/meld-fails-to-start-after-upgrading-to-10-13-high-sierra). I voted to leave closed but that was wrong according to the system, I should have reopened.

The reason why I voted to keep it closed was that the question is one sentence without any context. No explanation as to what happened when the program was trying to be started (did it freeze, open and close immediately thereafter) and no log and/or error message.

Maybe the 10 upvotes were a hint to reopen it. My point is that this is perhaps a bad question for an audit?

Comment: It's just one of those edge cases where a problem was caused by a software update that affected a decent number of people resulting in a poor looking question being useful due to circumstance.

Comment: (As per [here](/q/357890/6388243))

Comment: @KevinB But still, as the solution is already posted. Closing the question wouldn't harm anything. Especially considering that the question was answered by OP.

Comment: @mega6382 i mean... unless it's still an active problem people are facing, in which case the closed question wouldn't be found, and thus it would be asked again, wasting time. The downvote the question received as a response to this meta question has effectively made it ineligible to be an audit, so it's no longer a problem.

Comment: @KevinB Closing a question does nothing to stop it from being found.  *Deleting* it would.  No one has suggested deleting it.

Comment: I mean, what are you going to close it as? it's on topic, it isn't unclear, it doesn't need code or an MCVE, just make up your own reason?

Comment: @KevinB The question explains why they feel it merits closure.  If you feel that that isn't the case, then that's fine (I don't know enough about the topic to comment).  The point is that you don't keep a close-worthy question open just because you want people to be able to see it, because closing it doesn't stop them from being able to see it.  The only reason to keep the question open would be if it doesn't actually meet any closure criteria.

Comment: @KevinB it's a question about software being broken by an OS update. That's off-topic.

Comment: software used for programming.

Comment: @KevinB the question itself was not flagged to be closed by someone. It was a question to test if I was paying attention in the queue. My point is that it is a bad question to test someone imho.

Comment: @VDWWD i don't disagree, it's a bad audit. nothing new though. audits are chosen automagically.

Comment: Bad audit. Question is closed now.